# Not connected to Socks5 with username and password

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, proxy, socks

I am trying to use private proxy connection using PyProxy. However, I ran into a problem. If I add the login and password to the method then there will be no connection (it will just connect forever). However, if I change the "proxy settings" on the server and remove the login and password then the connection will happen immediately. I try to achieve the result so that there is support for both socks5 with log+pass and HTTP log+pass (but Pyproxy designed for SOCKS5 only. Maybe someone will propose another module for implementation.)

```
self.sock = socks.socksocket()
# this is work
sock.set_proxy(s_type, self.s_ip, self.s_port)
# NO WORK! (* - mask for log, passwd)
sock.set_proxy(s_type, self.s_ip, self.s_port, True, '*****', '******')
self.sock.connect((host,port))
```